# fnAddData effects speed of page loading when data is 30-40K

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

i'm adding data in datatable dynamically by using fnAddData and fnDraw functions, it's working as required but page took 10-20 seconds in loading.is there any way which speed it up? my code is as follow:

```
$(window).load(function() 
{
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "filters.php",
  data: {limit: 10000, start_from: (i * 10000)},
  success: function(response) {
    var array = JSON.parse(response);

    Object.keys(array).forEach(function(key) {
        oTable.fnAddData([
            array[key][1],
            array[key][2],
            array[key][3],
            array[key][4],
            array[key][5],
            array[key][6],
            array[key][7],
            array[key][8],
            array[key][9],
            array[key][10],
            array[key][11],
            array[key][12],
            array[key][13],
            array[key][14],
            array[key]['link']
        ], false);
    });
    oTable.fnDraw();

},
datatype: 'json'});
```

Answer (score 2):

you are getting 10000 results, have you considered requesting the data in smaller 'chunks' using a limit/offset and implementing either pagination or infinite scroll?

pseudocode -

```
function updateTable(data) {
    //use data to update table 
}

function getData(offset, limit, order, orderBy, filter) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ...
        ...
        data: {
            limit: limit,
            start_from: offset,
            order: order,
            orderBy: orderBy,
            filter: filter
        },
        success: function (data) {
            updateTable(data)
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    getData(0, 20, 'ASC', 'ID', null);

    $table.on('scroll', function () {
       //infinite scroll bits
       //if should load more data call getData(offset, limit)
    });

    $search.on('blur', function () {
        getData(0, 20, 'ASC', 'ID', $(this).val());
    });

    $orderBy.on('change', function () {
        var order;
        if (orderBy === $(this).val()) {
           order = 'DESC'
        } else {
           order = 'ASC'
        }

        getData(0, 20, order, this.val(), null);
    });
});
```

Comment: #joe fitter this line( data: {limit: 10000, start_from: (i * 10000)},) is not used for datatable, its for some other purpose. i'm fetching all record at once from database and returning a json encode format data which is then added to the table.

Comment: yes, I can see, and the browser obviously can't cope will receiving all results at once. Generally you will request data as and when you need it by making multiple ajax calls on scroll down or change page.

Comment: This definitely seems like the logical solution to the speed issues OP is experiencing.

Comment: actually i cant do that way(on scroll down or change page.) as you suggested because I've multiple checkbox filters on my page which does not display correct result if there is not complete record in datatable.

i've to fetch complete record when page load so that filters can work too.

Comment: in that case you should send the filters with the ajax request and filter on the server, just returning the results you require.

Comment: updated answer to include example of filters for server/db processing.

Comment: #Joe Fitter is there any wa to turn of parsing, formatting and sorting  in datatable, may be it speed up adding data?? i'm using datatable 1.9.4